# Angular Service Provide with a default value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

Consider an Angular Service that wraps **HTTP Client Module.**

```
export class HttpWrapperService {
  private apiKey: string;
}
```

Obviously, it has more features that are irrelevant.

Now I need to provide *HttpWrapperService* to the multiple modules with some unique default value. This default value should be assigned to a private data member, i.e. `private apiKey: string;`

---

### Observation:

As I have seen other imports with default values, I wonder how can this be implemented.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
GravatarModule.forRoot(GRAVATAR_CONFIG_TYPE1),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
  enabled: environment.production
})
```

---

### Current Way Out

Currently, I am using a static method to initialize a static variable. Not sure if that's the correct approach to this problem.

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(){
    HttpWrapperService.register(environment.apiKeyHeaders);
    UserService.registerEndpoint(environment.apiEndpoint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the api key value in the AppModule as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: 'API_KEY', useValue: '<apiKeyValue>' },
    HttpWrapperService
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The api key value can be injected as follows

```
export class HttpWrapperService {
    constructor(@Inject('API_KEY') private apiKey: string) {}
}
```

Comment: 'API_KEY' shall be available to use by all Services in provider list?